# reusable dynamic sidebar in Symfony 4 (Twig)?

Tags: symfony, twig, widget, symfony4

I recently started using Symfony 4 and I am creating my first website with this wonderful framework right now.

I have a sidebar that should be displayed in about half of my routes and the content of the sidebar should be filled with some data from a database.

Currently I use DI in all this routes and pass the result of the injected repository to the template (which includes my sidebar.html.twig) for the route.

```
public function chalupaBatman(FancyRepository $repository)
{
    $sidebarObjects = $repository->getSidebarObjects();
    $this->render('controllername/chalupabatman.html.twig', [
        'sidebarObjects' => $sidebarObjects,
    ]);
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to avoid this for every route I define in my controllers.

So far I found this topic on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41792059/how-to-include-a-reusable-widget-in-symfony-twig).

The User Mvin described my problem in a perfect way and also provided some solutions.

However there is still no answer to "what is the best practice" part also the topic is from 2017; therefor, the way to solve this may have changed in Symfony 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a TwigExtension solution. I'll describe how to achieve it and it would be great if you guys could provide some feedback.
Let me know if I produce massive overhead or miss something essential ;-)

Alright, first of all I created a TwigExtension via command-line

```
php bin/console make:twig-extension AppExtension
```

And then I modified the class to look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use App\Repository\ArticleRepository;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\Service\ServiceSubscriberInterface;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension implements ServiceSubscriberInterface
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('article_sidebar', [$this, 'getArticleSidebar'], ['needs_environment' => true, 'is_safe' => ['html']]),
        ];
    }

    public function getArticleSidebar(\Twig_Environment $twig)
    {
        $articleRepository = $this->container->get(ArticleRepository::class);
        $archive = $articleRepository->myAwesomeLogic('omegalul');

        return $twig->render('/article/sidebar.html.twig', [
           'archive' => $archive,
        ]);
    }

    public static function getSubscribedServices()
    {
        return [
            ArticleRepository::class,
        ];
    }
}
```

In order to activate Lazy Performance so our Repository and the additional `Twig_Environment` doesn't get instantiated everytime when we use Twig
we implement the `ServiceSubscriberInterface` and add the `getSubscribedServices`-method.

Therefor, our Repo and Twig_Environment only gets instantiated when we actually call `{{ article_sidebar() }}` inside a template.

```
{# example-template article_base.html.twig #}
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10">
            {% block article_body %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            {{ article_sidebar() }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Now I am able to define my templates for the article-routes like this:

```
{# example-template /article/show.html.twig #}
{% extends 'article_base.html.twig' %}
{% block article_body %}
    {# display the article here #}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You can inject the `Twig_Environment` by defining the following option, `new TwigFunction('article_sidebar', [$this, 'getArticleSidebar'], [ 'needs_environment' => true, 'is_safe' => ['html']])` , and changing the signature of your method to `public function getArticleSidebar(\Twig\Environment $twig) {`

Comment: Hello DarkBee, thank you for your input. I updated the answer so it uses your method to inject the `Twig_Environment`